# How to give history of messages to LLM using ConversationalBufferMemeory in Langchain

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

```
ValueError: variable **chat_history** should be a list of base messages, 
got [[AIMessage(content='hi'), HumanMessage(content='hi, i am rohan'), 
AIMessage(content='how can i help you?')]]
```

Below is the source code...

```py
def define_chat_model(history,input:str):
    
    llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo" ,api_key='sk-....')
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate(
            messages=[
                SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(
                    "You are a chatbot whose job is to make a conversation."
                ),
                # The `variable_name` here is what must align with memory
                MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name='chat_history'),
                HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{question}"),
            ]
        )
    memory =ConversationBufferMemory(return_messages=True,chat_memory=history,memory_key='chat_history')
    conversation = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt, verbose=True, memory=memory)
    ans = conversation({"question":input}).get('text')
    print(ans)
    return ans
```

```py
 base_message_list = messages_from_dict([{'type':'ai','data':{'content':'hi'}},{'type':'human','data':{'content':'hi, i am goku'}},{'type':'ai','data':{'content':'how can i help you?'}}])

        b = ChatMessageHistory()
        b.add_message(ans[0])
        b.add_message(ans[1])
        b.add_message(ans[2])
        print(isinstance(b, BaseChatMessageHistory)) #true
        res =define_chat_model(b,"what is my name?")
```